# NumberFormat setMaximumFractionDigits method

Tags: java, number-formatting

I am trying out the methods and the functionality of the class [`NumberFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#setMaximumFractionDigits%28int%29) and I have reached to a strange result. I compile and run the following program:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

Locale loc = Locale.US;
    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(loc);
    System.out.println("Max: "+nf.getMaximumFractionDigits());
    System.out.println("Min: "+nf.getMinimumFractionDigits());
    try {
        Number d = nf.parse("4527.9997539");
        System.out.println(d);
        // nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(4);
        System.out.println(nf.format(4527.999753));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

The output is:

```
Max: 3
Min: 0
4527.9997539
4,528
```

That means that it does not take into account any fraction digit. If I uncomment the line:

```
nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(4);
```

the output is:

```
Max: 3
Min: 0
4527.9997539
4,527.9998
```

In other words it works OK. What is actually happening with method `setMaximumFractionDigits()` and it does not bring the number containing 3 fraction digits in the first case?

Comment: Do you mean on setting manually the decimal places of a number ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found the answer finally. The method `setMaximumFractionDigits()` has an effect only on the method `format()`. It has nothing to do with `parse()`. In my code fragment I use the method `format()` after setting manually the number of fraction digits to 4, consequently it affects the result.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to set manually the number of decimal places use one of the following options:

Firstly:

```
  //sets 'd' to 3 decimal places & then assigns it to 'formattedNum'
   String formattedNum = String.format("%.3f", d); //variable 'd' taken from your code above
```

OR

```
  //declares an object of 'DecimalFormat'
   DecimalFormat aDF = new DecimalFormat("#.000"); 

  //formats value stored in 'd' to three decimal places
   String fomrattedNumber = aDF.format(d);
```

In my opinion the second option suits best for your case.

Answer (score 1):

The number created from parsed String has more fractional digits. But when you try to output it uses format's `MaximumFractionDigits` to create String from any given Number.

Comment: I cannot still understand the cause of the problem. Even I set the maximum digits manual (through the method setMaximumFractionDigits) to 3, it returns a number with no fraction part. I reckon it should have come up with a fraction part of 3 digits.

Answer (score 0):

I think that setMaximumFractionDigits sets how many digits will be considered by the formatter for rounding purposes, where your default at start is 3 (you displayed it by getting it)
So the nf.format will display up to 3 digits after rounding.
If no specific rounding policy given, format applies standard rounding which will round up if fraction is 5 or above.

Therefore when you call format, the default max fraction digits is 3, rounding apply on 4527.9997539 to 3 decimal places leaving you with 4528 which is your result.
If you allow 4 decimal by setting the fraction digits to 4, you get 4527.9998

You have not provided the formatter with a 'format' to use and force certain display of decimal points even when 0. So the default display comes from your locale (I'm guessing) - NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(loc);
If you do set the required format yourself as suggested by Joseph:
DecimalFormat aDF = new DecimalFormat("#.000");
Then you will get with same setup 4528.000 (which is same result you got already but formatted with 3 decimal places)